# What does OpenCV's cvAcc() do?

Tags: c++, image, video, opencv

Could someone please explains in simple, non-technical and non-mathematical terms what exactly does cvAcc do? I read that it it "accumulates", but have no idea what accumulates means.

Thanks

Comment: Worst question title ever. Suggestion: "What does OpenCV's cvAcc() do ?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accumulation is the result of adding (or summing).  It's kind of what the += does in C/C++.  So

```
cvAcc(image, accumulation, mask);
```

Is like

```
accumulation += image; // with the mask applied so only a region might be affected
```